# Boolean operators tail-call optimized?

Tags: stack-overflow, racket, boolean-operations, tail-call-optimization

While learning Racket and getting into programming in general I was defining *ormap* in two different ways:

```
(define (or-map proc lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) #false]
    [(proc (car lst)) #true]
    [else (or-map proc (cdr lst))]))


(define (or-map proc lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #false
      (or (proc (car lst)) ; <-- this one
          (or-map proc (cdr lst)))))
```

The following questions came to mind:

Is the second one tail-call optimized? I was not sure if the commented line gets thrown away (or the *(or ...)* stacks up it's arguments), because if it's #true the function call ends and if it's #false it should be irrelevant for further evaluation of the *(or ...)* statement.

So I ran the following test and looked at the task manager for memory usage:

```
(define (test)
  (or #f
      (test)))

(test)
```

The memory stayed the same. So I think I can conclude *(or ...*)* gets tail-call optimized? I assumed that stays true for *(and ...*)* and other boolean operators, but as I changed the *or* in *(test)* to *nor* the memory filled up.

So all in all, do I

- have some mistakes in my conclusions thus far?
- what's going on with the *nor-test*?
- rightfully assume both of my definitions of or-map are equivalent performance wise, or is one preferable over the other?
- (is my use of the task manager in this case even legitamate and is the phenomenon I witness there when the memory fills up stackoverflow or a implication thereof?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your username is `Tracer`, you may find it amusing that you can use `racket/trace` to examine this. :)

First an example of functions you would expect to use tail elimination and not:

```
#lang racket

(define (tail-call xs [results '()])
  (match xs
    [(list) results]
    [(cons x xs) (tail-call xs (cons x results))]))

(define (no-tail-call xs)
  (match xs
    [(list) (list)]
    [(cons x xs) (cons x (no-tail-call xs))]))
```

We can `trace` them and see this reflected in the call depth:

```
(require racket/trace)
(trace tail-call no-tail-call)

(tail-call '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; >(tail-call '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; >(tail-call '(2 3 4 5) '(1))
;; >(tail-call '(3 4 5) '(2 1))
;; >(tail-call '(4 5) '(3 2 1))
;; >(tail-call '(5) '(4 3 2 1))
;; >(tail-call '() '(5 4 3 2 1))
;; <'(5 4 3 2 1)
;; '(5 4 3 2 1)

(no-tail-call '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; >(no-tail-call '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; > (no-tail-call '(2 3 4 5))
;; > >(no-tail-call '(3 4 5))
;; > > (no-tail-call '(4 5))
;; > > >(no-tail-call '(5))
;; > > > (no-tail-call '())
;; < < < '()
;; < < <'(5)
;; < < '(4 5)
;; < <'(3 4 5)
;; < '(2 3 4 5)
;; <'(1 2 3 4 5)
;; '(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Next let's do that for your two definitions of `or-map`. We see the same, flat shape for both:

```
(define (or-map/v1 proc lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) #false]
    [(proc (car lst)) #true]
    [else (or-map/v1 proc (cdr lst))]))

(define (or-map/v2 proc lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #false
      (or (proc (car lst)) ; <-- this one
          (or-map/v2 proc (cdr lst)))))

(trace or-map/v1 or-map/v2)

(or-map/v1 even? '(1 1 1 2))
;; >(or-map/v1 #<procedure:even?> '(1 1 1 2))
;; >(or-map/v1 #<procedure:even?> '(1 1 2))
;; >(or-map/v1 #<procedure:even?> '(1 2))
;; >(or-map/v1 #<procedure:even?> '(2))
;; <#t
;; #t

(or-map/v2 even? '(1 1 1 2))
;; >(or-map/v2 #<procedure:even?> '(1 1 1 2))
;; >(or-map/v2 #<procedure:even?> '(1 1 2))
;; >(or-map/v2 #<procedure:even?> '(1 2))
;; >(or-map/v2 #<procedure:even?> '(2))
;; <#t
;; #t
```

Answer (score 2):

`and` and `or` do evaluate their last expression in tail position. This is guaranteed by the Scheme standard; see, e.g., http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.20.

`nor`, on the other hand, has to negate the result of `or`. By definition, that means that the result of `or` is not evaluated in tail position, since it has to be passed to `not` before going back to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking:

> rightfully assume both of my definitions of or-map are equivalent performance wise, or is one preferable over the other?

but note that your first function is *not* equivalent to the second one (does not produce the same result). You can verify this if you call them with:

```
(or-map (lambda (x) (member x '(1 2 3))) '(1 2 a))
```

The reason is that in the first function you return `#true` when `(proc (car lst))` returns something different from `#false`, but the function should return the value of `(proc (car lst))`. So the “right” version (that is the version equivalent to the Racket `ormap`) is only the second one.